# Image not there after tutum build

Tags: docker, tutum

I try to follow the tutorial here:

https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000539696-3-prepare-the-app

To me it looks like the image is build:

```
Build summary
=============

Using docker-in-docker
Building mounted app in /app
Image built in 5 minutes and 40 seconds
Tests passed in 4 minutes and 21 seconds
Image quickstart-python pushed in 0 minutes and 0 seconds
```

If I then switch to https://tutum.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000539697 it says the image is not there:

```
> tutum image push quickstart-python
Pushing quickstart-python to Tutum private registry ...
Tagging quickstart-python as tutum.co/shredding/quickstart-python ...
404 Client Error: Not Found ("could not find image: no such id: quickstart-python")
```

If i run `docker images` i can't see it as well.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up the build in docker build && docker push commands.